# javascript window.open failing to open in same browser window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a web page in the same window after validating user ID.  The html/javascript code is:

```
 <script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
  if(form.loginID.value == "" && form.loginPass.value == "") {
    window.open("mform.html","_self"); 
}
else {
    alert("Error Password or Username")  
      }
     }
 </script> 
 </body>
```

If I use _self the browser just reloads original page.  If I change it to _blank it opens a new window with the correct page loaded.  I have tried this in Safari, firefox and chrome browsers with the same results.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Try `window.location = "mform.html"` instead? More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Comment: Please mark my answer as helpful if it's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` is used to open a new window.

Use `window.location.href = 'mform.html'` to navigating the other URL in the same window.

Comment: I changed per your recommendations.  Now works in firefox and chrome but not safari.  In safari it still just reloads original page(index.html).

Comment: when do you call `check(form)`?

Comment: I found the fix for Safari.  The original html code was "<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onClick="check(this.form)"/>".  I changed it to "<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onClick="check(this.form);return(false)"/>" now the code works in all browsers.  Yair thank you for your recommendation.  It got me to the results.

Comment: changing window.location.href shows permission denied in IE9.